# WiX Burn Downgrade

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.9

So I have two installers, installer for my program, created with WiX, and installer that is installing my program and his prerequisites, and this installer is created with WiX Burn.

In both installers I need to support downgrade, and I have enable that in installer of my program:

```
<MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="yes" Schedule="afterInstallValidate"  />
```

And in installer downgrade is working perfectly.

In Burn installer I enabled downgrade:

```
<bal:WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="Resources\license.rtf"  SuppressDowngradeFailure="yes"/>
```

And I can install older version of my program with WiX Burn when newer version is already installed. But the problem that I have is that in ARP after downgrade with WiX Burn installer I have two entries. One is for newer version, that is removed but entry isn't removed, and one is for older version.

I am using WiX 3.9.

Did anybody have similar problem? Does anybody know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication/@SuppressDowngradeFailure doesn't enable downgrades; it merely turns a downgrade attempt from a failure to a success. It's intended for packages like the Visual C++ runtime that want to let a lower version run without interfering with a higher version that's already installed.

You might be able to support downgrades with a custom bootstrapper application but WixStdBA doesn't support it.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. At the end I decided to disable downgrade :)